# Create debian package with relative install path

Tags: package-management, software-installation, home-directory, environment-variables, deb

I am creating a debian package with a minimal layout (for a hypothetical package called "skate"). Here's the directory structure:

```
...
├── LICENSE
├── packaging
│   └── debian
│       └── skate
│           ├── DEBIAN
│           │   └── control
│           └── usr
│               └── local
│                   └── bin
│                       └── skate
├── README.md
...
```

But instead of installing the package into `/usr/local/bin` - as it would be - I would like to install it into `$HOME/.local/bin` - that is into a relative path (here: relative to the user's home directory).

How could this be done? Do I have to resort to ["maintainer scripts"](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#maintscripts) by first copying the content to a fixed location an then move it under `$HOME` (seems odd)?

Note: I do not want to change the installation procedure, e.g. I want the user to be able to type:

```
$ dpkg -i skate.deb
```

But the package installs some files into `$HOME/.local/bin` - which is only known at install time.

Comment: @user68186, unfortunately, no - updated my question, hopefully a bit clearer.

Comment: Packages aren't allowed to install to user home directories as a matter of policy. And usually users won't even be able to do `dpkg -i`, since the package database is owned by root.

Comment: @muru, thanks, that sounds reasonable.